Pass a hardcoded object parameter to a template
I have a template waiting for an object parameter :
#template.yml

parameters:
  - name: MyObject
    type: object

And a pipeline calling this template with a hardcoded value:
#pipeline.yml

trigger: none

stages:
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    MyObject:
      firstname: John
      lastname: Doe

This leads to an error :

A value for the 'MyObject' parameter must be provided.

For information, when the parameter come from the pipeline parameters, it works :
trigger: none

parameters:
- name: MyObject
  type: object
  default:
    firstname: John
    lastname: Doe

stages:
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    MyObject: ${{ parameters.MyObject}}

How can I pass a hardcoded object parameter ?

Unfortunately you can't create templates for parameters, only variables

I tested it in my pipeline and it works with the following Yaml. For more information, you can refer the document Template parameters
template.yml:
#template.yml
parameters:
- name: MyObject
  type: object

steps:
- script: echo ${{ parameters.MyObject.firstname }} ${{ parameters.MyObject.lastname }}

pipeline.yml:
#pipeline.yml
trigger: none

steps:
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
      MyObject:
        firstname: John
        lastname: Doe

Test result:

